# Magento connect doesnt install extension

Tags: php, apache, magento, permissions

After moving a site from local to remote server. I cannot get the magento conect manager to install extensions. No obvious info regarding this paticular error online.

If give an extension url....it will show the preloader for a few seconds, before returning to the connect page, with no error.

If use the package uploader, initially i had a 'could not move files' error...but changing certain dirs to 777 fixed this. I did set all folders to 777, to test if this helped. It didnt.

Anyone know this error? Otherwise manual extension installs for me :(
Could this be apache related....or moving files via FTP from local to remote server? I say this based on some forum posts i read.

Thanks
S

Comment: Did you copy the code from a one server to another?

Comment: Anything in magento's logs? (`./var/log/exception.log` & `./var/log/system.log`)

Comment: I ran into similar problem, but I am receiving `CONNECT ERROR: Can't open file package.xml for writing. Permission denied.`

Answer (score 8):

If the following files exist try removing (or renaming if you prefer to be safer) them.

```
downloader/connect.cfg
downloader/cache.cfg
```

These are generated by Magento the first time you use connect. The cache file stores a full path to your install, so when you move to a new server this likely isn't a valid path.

Comment: Hi,
The files are just regenerated...no change in the functionality i described. No entries in the apache error log...

Answer (score 6):

chmod 777 var/package/tmp/package.xml

should do the trick.

the directory is from your magento home directory.

Comment: and how to do this on windows ... still got the problem removed the connect.cfg and the cache.cfg on localhost via xampp

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you run out of disc space. I raised disk quota on my server for this account, and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH/CLI access and are using Magento 1.5+, try running `./mage mage-setup .`

If you're on Magento 1.3.x or 1.4.x delete the files in `/downloader/pearlib/cache/` and try again.

Comment: Hi,   i tried. No luck.

-Ran the setup, gave 2 x success msgs, then a 'community' folder already exists style msg. Cleared the cache. still the same.
-copied over the contents of the downloader folder from a fresh 1.6.1...removed .cfg files, cleared cache...refreshed connect page, tried to install extension......preloader screen for a few seconds then nothing.
-checked the exception, system, and apache logs....nothing.

What should the apache-user OWN....as at moment, root owns most files. All dirs currently set to 777 for testing.

Answer (score -1):

If you have cpanel hosting where the apache is configured to work with users such as nobody, apache etc.. then the problem is that. the owner of /home/user/public_html/var/package/tmp/package.xml will your cpanel user but this requires apache users permission. so the choice is to temporarily change the file permission to 777